# RayCast in python + pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

У меня появились некоторые вопросы по работе технологии raycast. Создавая свой проект pygame, я попытался сделать raycast и вот его версия:

```
def raycast(self):
    x1=hero.rect.x-self.rect.x
    y1=hero.rect.y-self.rect.y
    vh1=math.sqrt(x1**2+y1**2)
    for p in wolls:
        x=p.rect.x-self.rect.x
        y=p.rect.y-self.rect.y
        vh=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
        if vh<=vh1:
            self.see_hero=True
        else:
            self.see_hero=False
```

В начале функции я вычисляю положение игрока и npc, потом получаю расстояние от игрока до npc в пикселях(вроде).

Во второй части `for p in wolls:` я вычисляю расстояние от стены до npс. После вычисления расстояния от стены до npc я сравниваю результаты вычисленных расстояний:

Запуская свой проект, всё работает не так, как надо. Не могли бы вы помочь мне с этой проблемой?

Comment: Что значит "работает не так, как надо"?

Comment: Даже когда игрок за стеной npc идут за игроком, хотя не должны

Comment: у вас не правильный алгоритм. 

вам надо выпустить лучь от игрока до npc, если между ними не будет стены, то npc должен будет пойти за играком

Comment: Danis, я это понял ещё когда узнал что такое raycast, а вот как его сделать я не знаю

Comment: посмотрите некоторые советы здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316263/problem-with-finding-the-closest-intersection и здесь  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838657/2d-raycasting-and-rect-collision-in-pygame-line-of-sight-obstacles

Comment: спасибо, за информацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте создать переменную, включающую диапазон всех координатных точек стены (или только точек на её границе). При прохождении луча от NPC до Вас нужно будет рассчитать, проходит ли луч через координатные точки стены, если нет — то NPC идет за вами, иначе же он останавливается.